# Angularjs proceed with server call even if CORS does not allow a header value

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, interceptor

I have an AngularJS application that talks to various java services. In the application I have a global http header setting in an http interceptor. That means all the service requests from my application will get the header values.

Now the trouble is that all the services CORS settings won't allow this header value. Couple of services does, while others does not. The service calls to the servers that do not support the header fails, since the http interceptor always puts the header values.

Is there a better way to design, in the above said case, so as to avoid the issue stated?

Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a response interceptor, looking for a 401 status? If you get a 401, attempt to do the same request again without the headers this time. If this succeeds, 'whitelist' this domain to make all following requests without the headers that you don't want.

Otherwise, if you have a limited number of services that you are making calls to, maybe whitelist them inside of your request interceptor? This would probably be easier, but it's not very elegant.